# Why is Html table row scrolling breaks when scrolling filtered table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html table with search option, up+ down arrow key row scrolling option, highlighted row cloning option. 
Now, when I do search, the data gets filtered. When I try to scroll the data with the arrow keys then the data is scrolled order by id number of the rows. For ex:
if the filtered data is like this :

##-name-amt

1  aaa  100

2 ddd 111

5 ddd 000

here if I scroll the data then first row is highlighted, then the second row and then the highlight disappears and after I press the down arrow key 3 times then the third row is highlighted. That means, after highlighting the 2nd row it goes to serial no. 3 , then to 4 and then it comes and highlights serial no 5.

Why is this happening ??
Any help ?

```js
var $rows = $('#myTable tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

  var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;

  $rows.show().filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
  }).hide();
});

// highlight first row default
$("#myTable tbody tr:first-child").addClass("highlight");

document.onkeydown = moveAndAdd;

function moveAndAdd(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == "38") {
    // up arrow
    activeRow = $("tr.highlight"); /* get highlighted row */
    activeRow.focus();
    prevRow = activeRow.prev('tr'); /*very previous siblings*/
    if (prevRow.length > 0) {
      activeRow.removeClass("highlight"); /*remove highlight from active class */
      prevRow.addClass("highlight"); /* make very prev row highlighted*/
    }
  } else if (e.keyCode == "40") {
    // down arrow
    activeRow = $("tr.highlight"); /* get highlighted row */
    activeRow.focus();
    nextRow = activeRow.next('tr'); /*very previous siblings*/
    if (nextRow.length > 0) {
      activeRow.removeClass("highlight");
      nextRow.addClass("highlight");
    }
  } else if (e.which == 13) { //|| e.which == 32
    // Enter or Spacebar - edit cell
    e.preventDefault();
    cloneRow = $(".highlight").clone(true); /*clone highlighted row*/
    $("#cloneTable").append(cloneRow.removeClass("highlight")); /*append cloned row but remove class */
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

table {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px dashed #333;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: rgb(100, 200, 200);
}

th {
  font-weight: 100;
  background-color: rgb(200, 100, 100);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

th,
td {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:left;">
  <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Type to search" tabindex="1" autofocus>
  <table id="myTable" tabindex="2">
    <caption>Table Products</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>##</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>unit</th>
        <th>rate</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>intel</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>intel core</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>gigabyte</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>asus</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>400</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>asrock</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>intel core i3</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>intel core i7</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>intel core 2 duo</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>intel h110</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>cca</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>700</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Scroll list with Up &amp; Down arrow keys.<br> Press Enter to add the selected Row</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>

<div style="float:right;">
  <table id="cloneTable">
    <caption>Table Products Clone</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>unit</th>
      <th>rate</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are navigating between all rows and some of them are hidden after filtering. You have to iterate through them until you find a visible row. I did a sample using `do - while` loop which simple iterates through rows until it finds the next or previous visible row or it reaches the end.

```js
var $rows = $('#myTable tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

  var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;

  $rows.show().filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
  }).hide();
});

// highlight first row default
$("#myTable tbody tr:first-child").addClass("highlight");

document.onkeydown = moveAndAdd;

function moveAndAdd(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == "38") {
    // up arrow
    activeRow = $("tr.highlight"); /* get highlighted row */
    activeRow.focus();
    
    // Find previous visible row
    var prevRow = activeRow;
    do {
      prevRow = prevRow.prev('tr'); /* very previous sibling */
    } while (prevRow.length !== 0 && prevRow.is(":hidden"));
    
    if (prevRow.length > 0) {
      activeRow.removeClass("highlight"); /*remove highlight from active class */
      prevRow.addClass("highlight"); /* make very prev row highlighted*/
    }
  } else if (e.keyCode == "40") {
    // down arrow
    activeRow = $("tr.highlight"); /* get highlighted row */
    activeRow.focus();
    
    // Find next visible row
    var nextRow = activeRow;
    do {
      nextRow = nextRow.next('tr'); /* very next sibling */
    } while (nextRow.length !== 0 && nextRow.is(":hidden"));
    
    if (nextRow.length > 0) {
      activeRow.removeClass("highlight");
      nextRow.addClass("highlight");
    }
  } else if (e.which == 13) { //|| e.which == 32
    // Enter or Spacebar - edit cell
    e.preventDefault();
    cloneRow = $(".highlight").clone(true); /*clone highlighted row*/
    $("#cloneTable").append(cloneRow.removeClass("highlight")); /*append cloned row but remove class */
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

table {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px dashed #333;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: rgb(100, 200, 200);
}

th {
  font-weight: 100;
  background-color: rgb(200, 100, 100);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

th,
td {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:left;">
  <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Type to search" tabindex="1" autofocus>
  <table id="myTable" tabindex="2">
    <caption>Table Products</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>##</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>unit</th>
        <th>rate</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>intel</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>intel core</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>gigabyte</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>asus</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>400</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>asrock</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>intel core i3</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>intel core i7</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>intel core 2 duo</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>intel h110</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>cca</td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>700</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Scroll list with Up &amp; Down arrow keys.<br> Press Enter to add the selected Row</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>

<div style="float:right;">
  <table id="cloneTable">
    <caption>Table Products Clone</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>unit</th>
      <th>rate</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, for the help. Well the problem is solved in this part but I am seeing now that when I highlight row no. 4 before entering a search string and after that I enter a search string, for ex: "in" and then press the down arrow, it starts highlight from row 6 skipping the first  two rows.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the tr elements are still there although you 'filtered' them out. Therefore you don't highlight momentarily until you cross them. To get the real previous or next element that is in your filtered list:

```
function prev(node){
    var prev = node.previousElementSibling;
    while(prev.style.display !== "none"){
        prev = prev.previousElementSibling;
    }
    return prev;
}
```

This is currently what you can do since you only added display none to your hidden tr elements. A better way would be to add a class to your filtered tr elements so that you can do getElementsByClassName (also a live list, so you do it once), and iterate there

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Much appreciated.